# how to simplify an img array that uses many drawable ressources

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, drawable, increment

I have an array which contains several drawables needed by my main java code I use this to call them when needed:

```
mImagesArray = new int[]{R.drawable.img_0, R.drawable.img_1, R.drawable.img_2,...,R.drawable.img_m}
```

this direct implementation method works but imagine if i have an array containing +100 images, I would call each drawable value from img_1 to the final img_100 which is pretty frustrating.

What I need is a function which use an increment int i value that is defined by `(for i=0;i<m;i++)` so this function would look much simpler than the previous one that I used.. something like `mImagesArray = new int[]{R.drawable.img_i}` maybe ?

I hope you understood my question, basically I want an all-set function which requires only mImagesArray's number of elements..

edit ** mImagesArray is used in:

```
private void drawImage(Canvas canvas) {
        //Get the image and resize it
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                mImagesArray_ar[mImagesArrayIndex]);

        //Draw background
        // customWallpaperHelper.setBackground(canvas);

        //Scale the canvas
        PointF mScale = customWallpaperHelper.getCanvasScale(mImageScale, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        canvas.scale(mScale.x, mScale.y);

        //Draw the image on screen
        Point mPos = customWallpaperHelper.getImagePos(mScale, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, mPos.x, mPos.y, null);
    }
```

THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your code:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int myID =
    getResourceID("your_resource_name", "drawable", getApplicationContext());
```

Note: no path nor extension, in case of images.

---

You can even not use the `mImagesArray` array: just use `int myID = getResourceID("img_" + i, "drawable", getApplicationContext());`, where **i** is an integer (the same integer you would use as your array index).

Like this:

```
Bitmap image =
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    getResourceID("img_" + mImagesArrayIndex, "drawable", getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: can you please explain how to integrate 
int myID =
    getResourceID("your_resource_name", "drawable", getApplicationContext());

with 
mImagesArray = new int[]{R.drawable.img_0, R.drawable.img_1..

Comment: You can even not use the array... just use `int myID = getResourceID("img_" + i, "drawable", getApplicationContext());`, where **i** is an integer (the same integer you would use as your array index).

Comment: Der Golem, I cannot get rid of mImagesArray as I used it in another function, I updated my question so everyone can see it.

Comment: I edited my answer to demostrate you that **you can** get rid of it.

Comment: Sir, it's a pleasure. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to just create a string array with all the drawable names and then extract the drawable from the names.

I mean to say similar to this:-

```
String[] drawables=new String[100]
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
  drawables[i]="img"+i;
```

Then finally when you want it you get by name like this:-

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(drawables[i], "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

```
int x,i=0;
While(i<100){
    ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
    name="img_"+i;
    x=getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable, getPackageName());
    view.setImageResurse(x);
    mainActivity.addView(view);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this works. Code-only answers provide little insight into the reasoning.